# Преобразование регулярного выражения в недетерминированный конечный автомат

Tags: регулярные-выражения

При преобразовании regexp выражения в недетерминированный конечный автомат (например, с помощью алгоритма Томпсона) нужно ли скобки ([, ], {, }) включать в конструкцию? Например, начало такого выражения:

> (([ac]{1,2})([hi]{1,3}))+

сайт https://cyberzhg.github.io/toolbox/regex2nfa?regex=KChbYWVpb3V5XXszLDR9fFtlY3RdezQsNn0pKFtsbW5vcl17Myw0fSkpKw== преобразовывает вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот сайт не поддерживает такие сложные выражения. Внимательно посмотрите на то, что там написано в "Supported grammars".

Comment: Хотите воспользоваться тем сайтом - "упростите" выражение до того, которое станет ему понятно `(((a|c)(a|c)?)((h|i)(h|i)?(h|i)?))+`.  https://cyberzhg.github.io/toolbox/regex2nfa?regex=KCgoYXxjKShhfGMpPykoKGh8aSkoaHxpKT8oaHxpKT8pKSs=

Comment: @GrAnd большое спасибо!